# Handle upgrades with spring boot admin

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am using SBA for monitoring our microservices within AWS ecs clusters.

All looks OK, except upgrades, e.g when we spin new version of service we shutdown the old one once it becomes healthy. The thing is that the old one is shown as down and starts issuing notifications util we manually remove it. 
Any solution ?
I tried to use the instance de-reregistration setting but it doesn't work well since ECS probably just kills the tasks and not gracefully shuts down the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can issue a DELETE request to `/api/applications/<id>` during your deployment scripts to remove the application from the admin server